# DeepZoom Images not loaded in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, deepzoom

I have a sample application of silver light in which there are combination of normal images & deep Zoom Images. I have used DeepZoomTools.dll. Now if my first image is deep zoom image, it will not load.(Loading image displays continuously).In Fiddler, MultiTileSource xml is downloaded prefectly but in UI it shows in progress image. If I go to next image (second image) which is a normal image, it displays fine. After that if i go back to first image (Deep Zoom image), it works fine. So once normal image is appear, all images including deep zoom displays fine, but if first image is deep zoom image, it will not load until normal image gets displays. Do anybody has idea what might be the reason for this?